# Xamarin iOS access to address book request permission breaks application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to access address book in Xamarin.iOS app and I have tried this code:

```
var addressBook = AddressBook.ABAddressBook.Create(out NSError error);
if (addressBook != null)
{
    addressBook.RequestAccess((bool granted, NSError accessError) =>
    {
        if (granted)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    });
}
```

This code runs in to the `if` and `adressBook` is not null. But the `addressBook.RequestAccess(...)` doesn't run and application exits without falling into `catch` clause.

Does anyone know what is the problem with this code? How can I detect such errors, where to look for a log or something?

I'm using Xamarin in Visual studio 2017 on Windows 10 connected to a Mac and iPhone 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you include the NSContactsUsageDescription key in your info.plist?

For example:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your explanation to the user</string>
```

Not doing so usually results in a silent crash.

Also please note that the Address Book API was deprecated as of iOS 9 in favor of the [Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/). So you probably want to implement that one.

Comment: Thank you. Why this is not in the Xamarin documentation? Why this doesn't throw to my catch?! Nice one

Comment: Why it isn't in the Xamarin documentation I don't know. The exception however is by design from Apple if I am not mistaken. Why that is beats me.. Please accept it as an answer if it helped!

Comment: Sure in 5 minutes